# Unity takes 100% CPU in an empty scene

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, exe, cpu, cpu-usage

Why when we build a game scene with unity3d it uses 100% of CPU ?!

I mean it's not a matter of a scene with many objects and things or an empty scene, in both cases CPU usage is 100%.

Why?

How can I reduce it?

The reason that I want to reduce CPU usage is :
I want to run multiple `exe` in a dedicated server for a multiplayer game that I made with unity `UNET` and in this scenes, I have nothing except some functions and `syncvars` even I have no update function ...
I just want to make this `exe` files use less CPU to running better and increase performance.

Is that Possible to reduce CPU usage?

Comment: So you create new project in Unity with empty scene and cpu goes to 100%?

Comment: Have you tried turning your pc off and on again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution. It's just because of that I wasn't preset `targetframerate` on my scripts...

If we don't set it, then the game trying to run on highest frame rate as it can and if we run it on batch mode , then it will take all of the CPU usage.

Answer (score 7):

About the CPU usage. It may be that the only process you are running is that Unity Scene, so the PC use the 100% of the CPU for Unity since it doesn't need to allocate resources for other "heavy" applications (I guess not 100% since other necessary process for the System must be running as well). I guess if you run two scenes, it will around 50% for each...

Besides that, to make yous scene more efficient, you can try this things to make your game more efficient. There may be some more and you may not apply all of them. But you can take them into account as a start point:

**1- Static batching**

You probably have a ton of static geometry in your scene such as walls, chairs, lights, and meshes that never move. Mark them as static in the editor. Be sure to mark them as lightmap static in order to get baked lightmap textures. Instead of incurring a draw call for each individual object, objects marked as static can be batched into one combined mesh. Static batching has one crucial requirement: all the objects must use the same material. If you have static walls with a wood material and static chairs with a steel material, the walls will be batched into one draw call with one combined mesh, and the chairs in a separate draw call, with their own separate mesh.

**2- Texture atlasing**

As previously noted, each material incurs a draw call. You might assume that a wooden door and a steel chair might need separate materials since they use separate textures. However, if they can use the same shader, you can use texture atlases to create one material that both objects can use. A texture atlas is simply a larger texture that includes all of the smaller textures. Instead of dozens of materials loading dozens of textures, you can have one material loading just one texture. Each object can be mapped to use a texture on different coordinates on the atlas. You can do this manually in your art pipeline, but I’ve found Juan Sebastian’s Pro Draw Call Optimizer to be quite useful. It automatically generates texture atlases and swaps in new objects without messing with your assets.

**3- Dynamic batching**

Moving non-static objects can be dynamically batched into a single draw call. I’ve noticed this is CPU intensive and is calculated on each frame, but is a nice optimization. This only works on objects with have fewer than 900 vertices that use the same material. Use texture atlasing to create a single material for your dynamic objects and you get cheap dynamic batching!

**4- LODs**

LOD Groups are a cheap way to improve performance. Use assets that have multiple LODs and render lower-detail geometry for objects further from the camera. Unity can automatically fade between each LOD as the camera approaches closer.

**5- Fillrate, overdraw, and culling**

This gets to a topic I’m not too familiar with, but is worth paying attention to: reducing overdraw, where furthest objects are drawn to a pixel first, redrawing the pixel with each closer object subsequently on top. This wasn’t much of an issue on your average 1080p PC display but is significant issue with VR and mobile devices that have ultra-high resolution displays. A large amount of overdraw combined with a larger number of pixels kills your fillrate. Texture filtrate is one of the key limiting metrics in GPUs. Some solutions are provided out of the box with occlusion culling and frustum culling. Frustum culling doesn’t render objects that are outside of the camera’s frustum. No point rendering objects you can’t see! Occlusion culling gets rid of objects that are occluded by other objects in front of it. Rooms behind a door, for example, can be left out entirely. By default works occlusion culling works on your entire scene, but proper level design will allow you to cull out entire levels of your game.

LOD Groups can also cull objects that are too far away from the scene, further helping minimize fillrate.

**6- Level design**

If your game involves a player traveling from room to room, the naive solution has the entire game in one level. The downside, however, is memory consumption. Each object and material in each room is loaded to memory, even though they aren’t visible. Put each room into a separate level and asynchronously load them intelligently in code.

**7- Asynchronous loading**

Before the player approaches the door to the next room, load the next level. Don’t load this synchronously using Application.LoadLevel() as this will cause your game to hang while loading. As head tracking seizes momentarily, this will cause nausea and is a horrible experience for the player.

Instead, use Application.LoadLevelAsync(). You can find an example of this in the Oculus Mobile SDK BlockSplosion sample, under StartupSample.cs

**8- Baked lighting**

Turn off realtime shadows! Objects that receive dynamic shadowing will not be batched, and you’ll incur a severe draw call penalty.

On PC, you can get away with a single realtime directional light for nice dynamic shadows. Most modern PCs can provide gorgeous per-pixel shadowing. However on mobile, you want to stick to baked lighting and no realtime shadows. Bake your lighting with Hard and Soft shadowing at Very High Resolution.

**9- Shadows**

Especially for a performant mobile experience, jump back to old tricks for shadows on 3D objects. Semi-realistic shadows can be simulated with a simple 2D quad under your object with a blurry shadow texture.

**10- Light probes**

When you use baked lighting, your dynamic objects look out of place while static objects look great. You can use light probes to cheaply simulate dynamic lighting on your dynamic objects.

Light probes are baked cubemaps that store information about direct, indirect and even emissive light at various points in your scene. As a dynamic object moves, it interpolates samples of nearby light probes to approximate the lighting at that specific position. This is a cheap way of simulating realistic lighting on dynamic objects without using expensive realtime lights.

**11- Avoid transparent and multi-material objects**

Objects like glass see-through windows that use transparent shaders are very expensive. There’s a common practice of adding realism to walls by using a transparent material with a dust or rust texture along with a separate base diffuse material. This multi-material alpha blending is expensive; each material adds a draw call! Note however the multiple textures are not an issue; using multiple separate materials is expensive. Use one material and a shader that can blend multiple textures with alpha blending instead of multiple separate materials.

**12- Skinned mesh renderers**

Skinned mesh renderers are commonly used on characters that have animated rigs, enabling realistic mesh deformation using physics (ragdoll bodies) or custom animations (walk, jump, etc.).

Sad news: skinned mesh renderers don’t get batched. Each character in your scene can create several draw calls per eye. I’m not sure how to solve this yet.

Source: https://blog.bigscreenvr.com/12-performance-tricks-for-optimizing-vr-apps-in-unity-5-9849bb6aefa7

Answer (score 5):

There is not enough data to help you track down what the issue is, and it can be caused by alot of things. Try using the unity profiler to track down what is making your CPU spike

**Unity profiler**

Start off by using the unity profiler. This is a build-in tool from Unity that lets you inspect what part of the application is using what resource, the intesity of it, and the length of its usage.

If you go to window > Profiler you will see "CPU usage", divided into smaller sub-categories and a graph to visualise the cpu usage. You can click anywhere within the graph to get an overview of all the cpu usages within that frame.

the overview screen shows alot of information, the first ones you'll be wanting to look at being "total" and "time ms". Total being the total amount of CPU used in percentages. Time being the time it took in miliseconds.

Use this data to find what script/action takes up all your CPU and start optimizing from there.

more on unity's CPU profiler can be found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerCPU.html)

Comment: When I said I have nothing in my scene and it is empty , It does not make sense we use profiler or not !

Comment: @iman_sh you are contradicting yourself. does your scene contain a script or is it an empty scene?

Comment: @Bijan the only game object in my scene is empty with a simple script without any update.

Comment: @iman_sh just look at the profiler. if the profiler did not indicate a high CPU usage, this should be either a Unity bug which you should report it to Unity support, or there is something wrong with your hardware/OS/unity installation

Answer (score 1):

When running a scene in Unity, the objects are only rendered when they're visible in the camera. Unity automatically reduces its CPU needs when rendering a scene. There are of course some exceptions, but Unity is intelligent enough to reduce its unnecessary cpu usage. 
Your problem here can be due to multiple factors, and each factor has its own solution. There is no universal one. For example, it could be that you're having multiple gameobjects with huge textures, or that you're rendering a scene with the post-process package (that is memory/cpu consuming). Or it could be that your computer is simply not powerful enough, and that your target audience won't have that problem

Comment: I run EXE files in `batchmode` and in my scene i have nothing !! but it is not matter I run it in powerful system or weak system in both cases CPU usage always is 99 or 100 %

Comment: @iman_sh if you are running on a weak system and a powerful system, and the CPU usage is 99 - 100% with no scripts or any gameobjects in the scene then it is a bug you should report to Unity.

Answer (score 0):

To add to previous great answers.
**GPU Instancing** can improve performance and offload work from CPU.

Answer (score 0):

**Reboot Computer** Worked for me.

100% CPU Usage (i5-9400) Empty Scene in Empty 2D Project.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have lots of static objects. It was a static terrarian for me but after unchecking the static box, everything became normal.